# Question formulation sentence structure

Tags: questions

I wish to improve this sentence, which sounds bad to me but maybe acceptable:

> Are traditional investors at disadvantaged against high-frequency traders?

should I say:

> - Are traditional investors at disadvantaged versus high-frequency traders?
> - Are traditional investors at disadvantaged relatively to high-frequency traders?

any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three sentences that you've posted are ungrammatical.  I would write

> Are traditional investors at a disadvantage, relative to
>   high-frequency traders?

Comment: Great! that sounds better.

Comment: I agree, the three sentences in question are ungrammatical.  But note that besides "Are they at a disadvantage, relative to ..." being ok, so is "Are they disadvantaged, relative to ..." (and with a small difference in meaning).

Answer (score 0):

It is `to put at a disadvantage`

[Definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disadvantage)

I suggest

Do high-frequency traders put traditional investors at a disadvantage?

Or

Are traditional investors put at a disadvantage by high-frequency traders?

Comment: This isn't quite the same. These suggestions include an implication that it's a conscious action of the high-frequency traders to put the traditional investors at a disadvantage. While this may be true, the original sentences do not make this implication.

Comment: Right - so what is the passive version? Versus, relative to, something else?

Comment: I would use David Wallaces's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

None of your three questions above is correct. You should choose between:

> Are traditional investors **at a disadvantage**?

Or,

> Are traditional investors **disadvantaged**?

Next, about the preposition, you can choose among:

- with

Ex. [Long-term Sellers Disadvantaged **with** eBay TRS](http://www.ecommercebytes.com/C/letters/blog.pl?/pl/2009/10/1254672876.html)

- against

Ex. [Are Devils at a disadvantage **against** much-traveled Kings?](http://www.nj.com/devils/index.ssf/2012/06/do_devils_have_disadvantage_ag.html)

- compared to

Ex. [Etsy stores are at a disadvantage **compared to** online stores.](http://mywifequitherjob.com/etsy-stores/)

Comment: I would say "compared with" would have been better in that last example: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/compared-to-or-compared-with/